# Suitable Android device for engineering project

Tags: android, device, gsm, at-command, modem

I'm working on an Android application that can get low level information from a `GSM modem`. It depends on sending `AT-Command` to the modem and receive the answer. The application is done but there seems to be a problem with the device.

Most of the commands return error, that means the modem's manufacturer locked these engineering commands.

I wonder if there is a mobile device that's permit for the engineering purpose and let me send all `AT-Commands` I want.

note1: my mobile is Samsung Galaxy Win Duos.

note2: maybe there is an other way to get low level info. I saw this [link](http://azenqos.com). and it get every thing in `GSM modem` even L3 message.

**Conclusion:**

I want a mobile name that run all `AT-Command` (is nexus work for this app?) or an other way to get these info.

Comment: Try a purpose made modem, rather than a mobile phone.  Look at some cheap pre-pay modems if available in your country.  Usually you can see the modem manufacturer - check what AT commands you can find online.  Most of the AT commands from the popular vendors are in the public domain.  The interface available to you depends on the vendor, but in my experience, it is usually possible to use AT commands with commercial pre-pay modems.

Comment: @SList but my project is on mobile phone and I want to achieve it on android app.

Comment: OK, I get it.  If you seach on SO for questions tagged with [android][at-command], a few of the questions mention particular phone models.

Comment: I think that product to which you linked is using Qualcomm Gobi APIs.  If you look in the Qualcomm developer forum, there is a bit of discussion about using Gobi API on Android.  It seems not to be straightforward.

Comment: @SList , Could u give me more details.

Comment: I haven't used GOBI API on Android, so I can't help much, unfortunately.  Look on here: https://developer.qualcomm.com/forums/qdevnet-forums/3g4g-connectivity-gobi  there are 2 relevant questions.

Comment: @miraclemo I got stuck up with the same issue while designing a messaging system using Java. Got no solution for that.... M also eager to know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

AT Commands
What you should know

Different phones support different sets of AT commands. This means that a specific phone might not support all AT commands

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/AT_Commands this might be helpful.

Better u try out lower versions since they have less restrictions

You can go for T-Mobile modded phones since they are the ones with very less restrictions

Comment: I wanna android mobile. Are u sure that these Nokia devices have android OS. About at-commmands, I need GSM info and L3. another Q: Could the non famous mobiles like TwinMOS help me?

Comment: @miraclemo: Nokia does have X series mobiles which rus on Android. TwinMOS might help you. But you'll have a better shot with Gionee